# NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType Property Always Returns 0 On Android

Tags: c#, android, networking, mobile, xamarin.android

I'm building an application for personal use and I need to list all network interfaces' IP addresses and types.

I use the following code:

```cs
foreach (var networkInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    foreach (var addressInfo in networkInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
    {
        // Add the following string to a list and then display this list        
        var info = $"{addressInfo.Address}: {networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType} ({Enum.GetName(typeof(NetworkInterfaceType), networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType)})";
    }
}
```

The code above works fine on Windows but when I build and run it on Android `networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType` always returns `0` and `Enum.GetName(typeof(NetworkInterfaceType), networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType)` returns an empty string.

This behavior can be reproduced in applications built with Unity and Xamarin (even though the application has all the required permissions granted).

Comment: Can you provide an example sample output from both the success and failure scenarios?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the output on the success the result is an integer representing one of the following enum values (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype?view=net-6.0). On failure as clearly pointed out in the question the result is `0`.

Comment: Seems is a know issue that will be fixed 'soon' : https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/51303 // In this other post you have some suggested workarounds that I didn't tested myself: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/51984